# PhotoShop Scripting Selected Document Changed

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

I would like to know if there is a way using Photoshop scripting to raise an event when the user changes the active document in Photoshop.

Comment: That's a very good question. Since a script is designed to be run on one document at a time it's unlikely to change unless a new document is opened or closed. Your best bet is to check the name (and possibly path) of the document against the new one. In which case see if `documents.length` has changed

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  But how and where would raise an event to check for this

Answer (score 2):

You can use Notifiers, which are documented both in the Photoshop Scripting guide and in the Photoshop Javascript Reference.

An example is:

```js
app.notifiers.add("slct", File("~/Desktop/untitled.jsx"), "Dcmn")
```

Notifiers are PS jargon for Listeners, and the callback is a separate `.jsx` file which is read and executed when the event is caught.

In the above line of code, you're listening for the `select` event (which charID is `"slct"`), specifying also the optional class of `document` (`"Dcmn"`). Otherwise the callback would fire also when you select, say, a tool in the toolbar.

If you don't know what a charID is, it refers to ActionManager code, which is also (vaguely) documented in the guides I've mentioned above.